# How to parse JSON data without array name?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm new to JSON parsing. This code works. But how I can access directly to "likes" and "webformatURL" if  there were not "totalHits" and "hits" on JSON array?

```
 private void parseJSON() {

    String url="https://pixabay.com/api/?key=8947271-cb39739eaa5835e1eaa2f53c6&q=yellow+flowers&image_type=photo&pretty=true";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, 
        url, 
        null, 
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

                    for (int i =  0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String imageUrl = hit.getString("webformatURL");
                        int likeCount = hit.getInt("likes");

                        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, likeCount));
                    }

                    mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: How can you get a list item of list that does not exist?

Comment: I have another JSON api where there is not array header any it starts straight 
"id"
"name"

Comment: If you have another Json then you will write another parsing method for sure.

Comment: I am posting example of Gson library for you that would be helpful for you to simplify parsing method. and to code in 2 line for parsing.

Comment: I mean, how to do it ? There is not array header like in this example

Comment: I am not getting, how will you access childs if array does not present

Comment: Look to this api http://api.4pda.uz/android/news?limit=10&offset=0

Comment: I checked it. You can solve like answer below.

Comment: Nothing showing now

Comment: You will have to implement it as your reqirement

Comment: Wait, i write it for you.

Comment: I was bit busy, you can check the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to parse your json to directly ArrayList object.

You can do this.

```
        JsonArray itemArray = new JsonArray(response);
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Model>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<Model> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(itemArray, listType);
        for (Model model : yourList) {
            //  use this list
            System.out.println(model.toString());
        }
```

Here is your model class.

```
class Model {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private long date_add;
    private String poster;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public long getDate_add() {
        return date_add;
    }

    public void setDate_add(long date_add) {
        this.date_add = date_add;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return poster;
    }

    public void setPoster(String poster) {
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", date_add=" + date_add +
                ", poster='" + poster + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

To add Gson to your project. Just add this dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
}
```